# include/require path resolution

Tags: php, ubuntu, include

I have this situation in PHP where an `include` is being missed on one server but not the other server (I didn't set up the servers so I can't tell you much more; I'm not really a devops person so that is why I'm asking here). The code is identical on both servers, and both are running Ubuntu 14.04 with PHP FPM 5.5.9.

Here is an example:

file1.php

```
<?php
  var_export('1');
  include_once('somedir/file2.php');
  include_once('include.php');
?>
```

include.php

```
<?php
  var_export('2');

  function foo() {}
?>
```

somedir/file2.php

```
<?php
  var_export('3');
  //notice it has the same name as include.php in the starting directory
  include_once('include.php');
?>
```

somedir/include.php

```
<?php
  var_export('4');

  function foo() {}
?>
```

If I navigate to file1.php, the working server will print 1, 3, 2. If I navigate to file1.php on the "broken" server, I will get an error saying function foo can't be redefined.

Is there some setting on my "broken" server that is causing it it include that second include? Thanks!

Comment: basically thats what the error says, only define that particular function once

Comment: If you're including two files that both try to define `foo()`, it reporting an error is **not** what you'd consider broken. Perhaps you have error reporting off on the one that doesn't complain.

Comment: my question is why one server is including `include.php` and why one is including both `include.php` and `somedir/include.php`.

Comment: Are both functions (foo) different or the same? It's very unlikely they are both being successfully called. You cannot have two functions with the same name.

Comment: im not sure, but it doesnt matter. my point is why is one include not being included on my working server? maybe a php setting that resolves include/require paths differently?

Comment: Check for `set_include_path` on one server or the other.  I'd bet that the one that works has the include path set.  I think `phpinfo();` will tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in file1.php on both systems: `echo get_include_path();` and see what happens (tm).

Comment: Um, and tell us what happens, OK?

Comment: it looks like one is using a matching pattern in nginx to direct php files to php fpm, and sets the include_path at that time to $document_root/someotherstuff. going back to a normal include path which starts with . seems to produce the behavior i would expect. thanks!